# How To Send JSON Array Object POST Request Using jQuery Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

*I need To send JSON Array Object to my back-end using ajax. I can send this data using POSTMAN But I can find out the way to send these data using ajax...I really need your help.*
**This is my JSON Array Objec**t -

```
{
  "bookingID": "B005",
  "rentDate": "2021-06-15",
  "returnDate": "2021-06-27",
  "bookingStatus": "",
  "rentStatus": "",
  "custNICNumber": {
    "custNICNumber": "C001",

  },
  "driverNICNumber": {
    "driverNICNumber": "D001",

  },
  "bookingDetails": [{
      "bookingDetailsID": "",
      "lossDamage": 12000.00,
      "lossDamageImage": "lossDamageImage",
      "bookingID": {
        "bookingID": "B005",

      },
      "driverNICNumber": {
        "driverNICNumber": "D001",

      }
    },
    "vehicleRegID": {
      "vehicleRegID": "V001",

    }
  },

  {
    "bookingDetailsID": "",
    "lossDamage": 12000.00,
    "lossDamageImage": "lossDamageImage",
    "bookingID": {
      "bookingID": "B005",

    },
    "driverNICNumber": {
      "driverNICNumber": "D001",

    }
  },
  "vehicleRegID": {
    "vehicleRegID": "V001",

  }
}
]
}
```

*And This Is The Method I am trying to send my data to my back-end..*

```js
$('#btnPlaceBooking').click(function() {
  let bookingID = $('#txtBookingID').val();

  let rentDate = $('#txtRentDate').val()

  let returnData = $('#txtReturnDate').val();

  let custNICNumber = $('#txtCustomerID').val();
  let driverNICNumber = $('#txtDriverID').val();

  console.log("AddDetails")

  $.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: "http://localhost:8080/Back_end_war_exploded/booking",
    contentType: "application/json",
    async: true,
    data: JSON.stringify({
      bookingID: bookingID,
      bookingStatus: "",
      rentData: rentDate,
      rentStatus: "",
      returnData: returnData,
      custNICNumber: custNICNumber,
      driverNICNumber: driverNICNumber
    }),
    success: function(date) {
      console.log("AddDetails" + date)
    }
  })

})
```

**I Really need Your Help..Thank You..!**

Comment: Whats the error? whats not working? Are you getting client side  or server side error?

Comment: Error Status Code - 500...When I  Send This Data Without Json Arry Object. Thre Is No Error. But With Array...I can't Sned

Comment: But you seem to be sending a custom object in your .ajax function and not the object that you have posted at the beginning.  Also, 500 is a  server error, which means that your data is not in the  right format or is incomplete.

Comment: Yes..My data is not in the right format. Because I don't know how to send an array. Can You help me..?